# JQUERY Mobile popup causes a width scrolling

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile for an application.
I added to pages a popup dialogs and it work's just fine.

the problem is that when i changed my `jquery JS` files to `rtl.jquery.mobile-1.2.0`,
because i want to use a ui that match right to left actions, all of the pages that has popups
get a `width x scrolling effect`.

anybody know why? or how i can fix that?
because i don't want to give up about the `rtl ui`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can leave the  `jquery JS` file and add this attribute to the `data-role="page`

```
dir='rtl'
```

Comment: I already tried that. it doesn't work on jquery mobile elements. that is why i downloaded the rtl jquery js and css

Comment: I finally solved scroll problem with a overflow hidden to page